# How can i change the below code ...... body: SafeArea( to body: column(.... in flutter

Tags: flutter

```
 Widget build(BuildContext context) {
   return Scaffold(
      body: SafeArea(
        child: ListView(
          //padding: EdgeInsets.symmetric(vertical: 30.0),
          children: <Widget>[
            SizedBox(height: 20.0),
            MainTest(),
            SizedBox(height: 20.0),
            MainCheck(),
          ],
        ),
      ),
```

Comment: What do you want?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

```
 Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      resizeToAvoidBottomInset: false,
      body: Column(
        children []);
```

Comment: Please read "[answer]" and "[Explaining entirely code-based answers](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/392712/128421)". It helps more if you supply an explanation why this is the preferred solution and explain how it works. We want to educate, not just provide code.